# Have a each() with if statement not working

Tags: javascript, cypress

### Problem

I only want the commands in the if logic to happen if the 3rd default button is visible, but it throws an error saying its parent has the css class of visibility: hidden. When you need to remove that state the 3rd default button becomes visible so I'm not sure why it isn't passing.

### Desired Behaviour

I want it so for each state that is underlined to click on them to unselect them. Then the `if` statement is to take care of those who need to be actually removed, because they have info filled out for them, and so if the 3rd default button is visible, which is the <kbd>remove</kbd> button, then to execute the code inside the `if` statement which is to make sure the other default buttons are hidden and click the <kbd>remove</kbd> button.

### Code

```
it('deletes all selected states', () => {
  cy.get('span[class*="css-ddft8r-StateText"]').each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .filter(':has(span[class*="css-1qkbmzm-Underline css-1x6iasc4"])')
      .click({ multiple: true });
    if (cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]').eq(3).should('be.visible')) {
      cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]')
        .eq(0)
        .should('be.hidden');
      cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]')
        .eq(2)
        .should('be.visible');
      cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]')
        .eq(3)
        .click();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Cypress commands return Chainer object - it is inner Cypress entity which can't be used with conditionals as object is always recognized as true within if statement.
   So please give a chance for jquery:
   `if(Cypress.$('[data-cy=default-buttons]:contains("remove")').is(':visible')){
   // do assertions
   cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]:contains("remove")').click({force: true})
   // as parent is hidden, we can ommit click visibility check by passing force: true
   }`
2. `*=` is checking that attribute contains part of passed string, so your selector could be simplified to:
   `[class*="StateText"]`
3. Whole test seems as overengineered and not working properly with these each cycle and conditional inside. Maybe you dont even need to check buttons for each element and move assertions out of loop. Example repository would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I ended up using was actually just using `.each()` instead of the `if` statement within it. We figured out we could utilize a ternary inside of a `data-cy` due to those css classes being unstable/unreliable and this took care of not having to write an `if` statement.

We did roughly this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=example_data_cy]').each($el => {
//click on the state if it was selected to unselect it
```